# SQL Select, different than the last 10 records

Tags: sql, select

I have a table called "dutyroster". I want to make a random selection from this table's "names" column, but, I want the selection be different than the last 10 records so that the same guy is not given a second duty in 10 days. Is that possible ?

Comment: I feel like I should use SELECT TOP clause, within a "do..loop.." ?

Comment: Which database vendor's SQL are you using? Also, can you post the queries you've tried, and the results?

Answer (score 0):

Create a temporary table with only one column called oldnames which will have no records initially. For each select, execute a query like

`select names from dutyroster where dutyroster.names not in (select oldnamesfrom temporarytable) limit 10`

and when execution is done add the resultset to the temporary table

Comment: Waow, impressing, thanks buddie, I will give it a try

Comment: (A) You would need to ORDER BY something reliable to ensure the cache doesn't get shuffled by the indexer etc and thus might return something other than the latest 10. (B) But you don't need to maintain everything anyway, only the latest 10. Next time around, DELETE FROM the table before INSERTing the latest 10.

Answer (score 0):

The other answer already here is addressing the portion of the question on how to avoid duplicating selections.

To accomplish the random part of the selection, leverage `newid()` directly within your select statement.  I've made this [sqlfiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/c521b/1/0) as an example.

```
SELECT TOP 10 
    newid() AS [RandomSortColumn], 
    * 
FROM 
    dutyroster
ORDER BY 
    [RandomSortColumn] ASC
```

Keep executing the query, and you'll keep getting different results.  Use the technique in the other answer for avoiding doubling a guy up.

Answer (score 0):

The basic idea is to use a subquery to get all but users from the last ten days, then sort the rest randomly:

```
select dr.*
from dutyroster dr
where dr.name not in (select dr2.name
                      from dutyroster dr2
                      where dr2.datetimecol >= date_sub(curdate(), interval 10 day) 
                     )
order by rand()
limit 1;
```

Different databases may have different syntax for `limit`, `rand()`, and for the date/time functions.  The above gives the structure of the query, but the functions may differ.

If you have a large amount of data and performance is a concern, there are other (more complicated) ways to take a random sample.

Answer (score 0):

you could use `TOP function` for SQL Server
and for MYSQL you could use `LIMIT function`

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this would help...

```
SELECT TOP number|percent column_name(s)
FROM table_name;
```

Source: http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_top.asp